# regex for --- (triple dash) in bash

Tags: regex, bash, rename

I am trying to do a batch rename of files with `rename`. I can execute most of my changes but one is eluding me.

I am using this

```
find cracking-the-coding-interview -execdir rename 'y/---/-/' '{}' \+
```

The idea works fine for other regex, but this replacement does nothing. I tried replacing with a different item instead of dash

```
y/---/a/
```

and it replaced every dash with an a! not just those three connected. I also tried

```
'y/-{3}/-/'
```

I have a file structure something like this:

```
├── cracking-the-coding-interview
│   ├── algorithms
│   │   ├── bfs---shortest-reach-in-a-graph
│   │   │   ├── description.md
│   │   │   ├── solution.java
│   │   │   └── solution.js
│   │   ├── binary-search---ice-cream-parlor
│   │   │   ├── description.md
│   │   │   └── solution.js
│   │   ├── dfs---connected-cell-in-a-grid
```

Comment: Try to escape, like `\-\-\-`.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that. tried escaping and doesn't work.

Comment: Try with `s/`, not `y/`.

Comment: yes, thats it! whats the difference? I can't find anything on manpage. I would normally s for sed though

Comment: The manual for `rename` says that the regex is a Perl regex. In Perl, `y/` (synonymous with `tr/`) does a *translation*, whereas `s/` does a string regex *substitution* as you would expect.